# Pinescript-Exit position error. Strategy.exit randomly open opposite position, due to not counting some position close by "strategy.close"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use two strategy.close and one strategy.exit on one entry. Normally it works fine. however I don't know is that because close and exit don't talk to each other in the same bar or not. sometimes, after strategy.close active close the 50% of position, and the following strategy.exit still want to exit 100% of potion. And such action cause create the opposite position.

```
**///FIRST STOP LINE**
if Count1bull_check:=true
    bull_low:= low

**////BUYING LOGIC**

bull_ctrend= bull_check and val[1]<val and bull_low <close and val<0
if bull_check and val[1]<val and val<0
    bull_check:=false

**///RESET**
if strategy.opentrades ==0
    bull_out1_trend_check:=false
    bull_out2_trend_check:=false
    bull_out1_trend_notdone :=true
    bull_out2_trend_notdone :=true
    bull_out1_low:=0

**///BUYING**

if bull_ctrend
    strategy.entry('OpenLong_ctrend', strategy.long)
    bull_check:=false 
**////SET UP FOR CLOSE OR EXIT PRIORITY**
if bull_out1_ctrend
    bull_out1_ctrend_check:=true
if bull_out2_ctrend
    bull_out2_ctrend_check:=true

//counter trend exit order hierarchy
bull_1_ctrend =bull_out1_ctrend_check == true
bull_12_ctrend =bull_out1_ctrend_check== true and bull_out2_ctrend_check== true
**////CLOSE AND EXIT CON**

if (strategy.opentrades>0 and bull_out1_ctrend and bull_out1_ctrend_notdone) and ta.barssince(bull_ctrend)>=1

    strategy.close("OpenLong_ctrend",qty_percent=50,comment="c50%")
    bull_out1_ctrend_notdone := false
    bull_out1_clow:=low

if bull_out1_ctrend_notdone==false and bull_out2_ctrend and bull_out2_ctrend_notdone

    strategy.close("OpenLong_ctrend",comment="close all")
    bull_out1_ctrend_notdone := true
**////EXIT**
strategy.exit("longcx","OpenLong_ctrend", stop=math.max(bull_low,bull_out1_clow),comment=bull_low<bull_out1_clow?"c1out":"clow")
```

the red circle is the susses one, and the blue one is the one which open the opposite position due to over execute exit position
[image: the red circle is the susses one, and the blue one is the one which open the opposite position due to over execute exit position]

I to adjust exit qty_percent=50 also, but the right one will become the wrong one. so....
Due to the strategy.close one will execute by market price and strategy.exit will use limit price, which I will need them both. So I couldn't use only strategy.exit or strategy.close to do the whole work.

most of time the program works fine, but if the strategy.exit and strategy.close happens at once in the same bar, the error will random happens (actually, the strategy.close will execute due to the previous bar, and the strategy.exit will happens on the same bar strategy.close execute)

Comment: Try to cancel exit (`strategy.cancel("longcx")`) for the bar when you close the position by `strategy.close()`.

Comment: thanks Andrey, I find out the reason cause the random error, is due to the "open price" lower than the "stop price". for example, if the first bar trigger the strategy.close, it will execute until second bar, in the mean time if the "open price" of the second bar is lower than the "stop price" made by first bar, it will cause error.  

if I use strategy cancel("longcx"), it will works fine, however, the "stop price" will gone. thanks anyway. : )